# SSRS export report using C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I want to ask is there any way to export SSRS report programmatic using C#

Export through ssrs report using C# When reports Run it should save on local disk
Please see the image screen shot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NbXO.jpg)

Like i dont want to export like this as above screen shot...

i want it like when report click it should be export or save in local disk

is there any code then please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  Search for "ReportExecutionService SSRS C#".  You can then just specify whether you want Excel or PDF in the line ".Render(format, ...."

An example can be found at http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsreportingservices/rendering+reports+programmatically

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automatically save the report when you display it with the Report Manager website, then it is not possible.

You create a client/web application and use the [Reporting Services Web Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc282808%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154606%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) are the supported formats) to render the report, but you wouldn't be able to trigger your application from the Report Manager.

If your users really need to display and save the report at the same time, then you could use [ReportViewer controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671.aspx) in your application and add some code to save the report automatically when the user display a report.
It would fit your needs but will take some time to develop, because you will need to redevelop a "report explorer" to browse in the different folders if you need to have the same user experience.